# How do I supply parameters to a constructor called by another constructor?

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct, constructor

In my project, I have four structs: `Node`, `Ring`, `Disc`, and `Graph`.

- a `Ring` contains two vectors of 12 `Node`s each
- a `Disc` contains a vector of `Ring`s (a parameter tells the constructor how many)
- a `Graph` contains a vector of `Disc`s (again, the number is supplied by a parameter)

Everything works fine except `Graph`s. If I want to construct a `Disc`, I allow the number of `Ring`s it contains in its `std::vector<Ring> rings` to be set via the constructor like so:

```
Disc::Disc(size_t r) : rings {r} {};
```

But if I want to construct a Graph, I somehow need to set *both* the number of Discs *and* the number of Rings in each Disc. So I guess what I need is a way to input parameters to the Ring constructors when they get called for each Disc that is being constructed. I am new to programming, and unfortunately I haven't been able to find any tutorials on how to tell the constructor what to do in a situation like this. But perhaps I am going about this in the completely wrong way.

Comment: So, you basically have something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/EzecfT)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, that's pretty much exactly it. At the moment I'm not worried about the values of any members of the vector items, just how many are in each Ring/Disc/Graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it possible to initialize each of your classes directly with a container of the same type that you store in the classes. That way you don't have to supply how many of each there are in them.

Here are some made up versions of your classes.

```
struct Node { int x; };

struct Ring {
    Ring(std::array<std::array<Node, 12>, 2> a) : nodes(std::move(a)) {}
    auto begin() { return nodes.begin(); }
    auto end() { return nodes.end(); }
private:
    std::array<std::array<Node, 12>, 2> nodes;
};

struct Disc {
    Disc(std::vector<Ring> in) : rings(std::move(in)) {}
    auto begin() { return rings.begin(); }
    auto end() { return rings.end(); }
private:
    std::vector<Ring> rings;
};
 
struct Graph {
    Graph(std::vector<Disc> in) : discs(std::move(in)) {}
    auto begin() { return discs.begin(); }
    auto end() { return discs.end(); }
private:
    std::vector<Disc> discs;
};
```

You could then create a whole `Graph` object in one go if you'd like

```
Graph graph(
    { // discs
        { // disc 0
            { // rings
                { // ring 0
                    { // array initialization
                        { // outer array
                            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12}, // nodes 0 (inner)
                            {13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24}  // nodes 1 (inner)
                        }
                    }
                },
                { // ring 1
                    {
                        {
                            {25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36},
                            {37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        { // disc 1
            { // rings
                { // ring 0
                    {
                        {
                            {49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60},
                            {61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72}
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h7jzfb)

Comment: Thank you, this is quite useful. I will consider something like this implementation as I build on the project.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are flexible, they can be constructed empty and filled afterwards.

In Your scenario, You would do something like this.

```
Graph::Graph(size_t nDiscs, size_t *nRingsPerDisc) : discs{}
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nDiscs; i++)
        discs.push_back(Disc(RingsPerDisc[i]));
}
```

Comment: I could be doing something wrong but I can't get this to compile

Comment: @slynt What kind of compile error do You get?

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out a solution that seems to work nicely. For the sake of documentation, here's the definition I've now given to the `Graph` constructor:

```
Graph::Graph(size_t d, size_t r) : discs (d, *new Disc {r}) {};
```

Comment: That appears to be working, but it is almost definitely not what You wanted. You fill `discs` with `d` copies of the exact same disc, and then You don't delete that original disc (every call to `new` should be at some point followed by a call to `delete`) However, if You want all discs in a graph to be equal size, this *is* the most straightforward way, just don't use the `operator new` here. Simply writing `: discs(d, Disc{r}) {}` should work, without any side effects.